# After the following program is finished, how many bytes are written to the file ourOutput.txt?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class WriteFile
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            PrintWriter first = new PrintWriter("ourOutput.txt");
            first.println("1 2 3");
            first.close();

            PrintWriter second = new PrintWriter("ourOutput.txt");
            second.print("4 5 6");
            second.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
         // error handling code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you run and try it?

Comment: Are you asking, how many are written or what is the final size ?

Comment: I would say 11 bytes, but also depends on the length of `system property line.separator`

Comment: Try CountedOutputStream from `Apache Commons`

Comment: Probably trying to cheat his way through an interview test.

Comment: Yeah, but I am being pendantic, the original 6 bytes are written to the file, but then the file gets trashed.

Comment: Using uppercase is considered SCREAMING; thus rude and impolite. You are disrespecting this community. You see, this is not a place where you drop your requirements and other people do the thinking for your.

Comment: @RenéLink Oh, I liked your comment

Comment: @Pujan the final size could be 5 up to 20 bytes long depending on your settings and your OS.  It is most likely A, but could be C.

Answer (score 1):

SamTebbs33 is right; the second set of writes overwrites what the first set of writes did, so in the end the file will contain "4 5 6".

However, how many **bytes** the file will contain, is impossible to say, because it depends on the character encoding that's being used. Since no character encoding is specified in the code, the default character encoding of the system will be used (see API docs of the [`PrintWriter` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.lang.String-)) and we don't know what that is on your system.

Different character encodings use different numbers of bytes per character. For example, if it would be UTF-8, then there would be one byte per character and the total number of bytes would be 5. But UTF-16 uses 2 bytes per character so the total number of bytes would be 10.

If this is a question from some kind of quiz or exam then it's a poor question, because information is missing so that the question can't be answered accurately.

Answer (score 0):

If each character is encoded as two bytes and the line seperator is `\n`, then the number of bytes written would be 11. The reason why it is not 22 is because you are writing "1 2 3" to the file (with a line seperator) but then overwriting that when you next declare the `PrintWriter` and print the next `String`.